# Angular2 navigate to anchor on another page

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

Basically the title says it all. I want to navigate from one page to a certain id on another page in Angular2.

inside the bar/bar.component.html I've got a button which should take me to foo#orange:

```
<a [routerLink]=" ['/foo'] " fragment="orange" href="#orange" class="button">hello orange</a>
```

anchor inside foo/foo.component.html:

```
<article class="orange" id="orange">
```

What happens is, that the browser opens "/foo#orange" but stays on the top of the page.

[EDIT]
This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595) in Angular2.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular but I would patch this by extending the router to scroll the matched element into view if one is provided, this shouldn't require a huge amount of code to achieve.

Comment: @Yoda - it seems so ... thanks anyway