# Navigate multiple times to the same anchor Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a pretty simple Angular 2 app and I'm trying to navigate to the hrefs of the page. I looked at different questions like [Angular2 navigate to anchor on another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702568/angular2-navigate-to-anchor-on-another-page) or github issues like this one   https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595 and I ended up having a working solution which is having this piece of code in my component:

```
constructor(router: Router){
        router.events.subscribe(s => {
            if (s instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                const tree = router.parseUrl(router.url);
                if (tree.fragment) {
                const element = document.querySelector("#" + tree.fragment);
                if (element) { element.scrollIntoView(element); }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

that works absolutely fine however if I want to go again to the same href it doesn't work and the page doesn't navigate to the anchor. My question is whether the subscribe needs to be placed somewhere else or whether I need to tell my component not to unsubscribe (guess that's what's happening?)?

Comment: If I understand your question, you are wanting to reload the same route you are on. What about using a document.reload() command?

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this?